# For second native function showing UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for .stringFromJNI2()

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

Can any body tell me please whats wrong with this code. This is crashing with stacktrace

```
    06-27 12:02:12.842 20619-20619/? E/art: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.rana.nativesupport.MainActivity.stringFromJNI2() (tried Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI2 and Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI2__)
06-27 12:02:12.843 20619-20619/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: com.rana.nativesupport, PID: 20619
                                                   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.rana.nativesupport.MainActivity.stringFromJNI2() (tried Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI2 and Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI2__)
                                                       at com.rana.nativesupport.MainActivity.stringFromJNI2(Native Method)
                                                       at com.rana.nativesupport.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
                                                       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                                                       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

My Activity class code is

```
package com.rana.nativesupport;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // Used to load the 'native-lib' library on application startup.
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("native-lib");
    }

    /**
     * A native method that is implemented by the 'native-lib' native library,
     * which is packaged with this application.
     */
    public static native String stringFromJNI();
    public static native String stringFromJNI2();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Example of a call to a native method
        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sample_text);
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(stringFromJNI()));
        tv.setText(String.valueOf(stringFromJNI2()));
    }

//    public native String intFromJNI();
}
```

and native-lib.cpp is here

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

extern "C"

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject obj/* this */) {
    std::string hello = "C++ is goddamn serious";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
};

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI2(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject obj/* this */) {
    std::string hello = "C++ is goddamn serious";
    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
};
```

Tried almost everything but still getting Exception
**UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.rana.nativesupport.MainActivity.stringFromJNI2() (tried Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI2 and Java_com_rana_nativesupport_MainActivity_stringFromJNI2__)**

When i execute the app it closes saying unsatisfied link error for the second function but working fine if i am using only one native method.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I believe the `extern "C"` only counts for the first function that is defined after it. Could you try adding braces and put your functions in there? Like `extern "C" { ... /* Your JNI functions */ }`

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE You are my saviooour... Thanks a lot ...saved my week.

Comment: I'll turn it into an answer, please consider upvoting it if it helped you

Comment: You didn't `#include` the header file created by `javah`.  That would also solve the problem, and it's definitely the easiest way to handle larger JNI interfaces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extern "C" only counts for the first function that is defined after it. If you add braces to it and put your functions in there, like below, it will work

```
extern "C" { 
    /* Your JNI functions */ 
}
```